# Machine learning Spam Classification

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

```
import numpy as np # linear algebra
import pandas as pd # data processing, CSV file I/O (e.g. pd.read_csv)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os

dataset = pd.read_csv(r'emails.csv')
dataset.columns #Index(['text', 'spam'], dtype='object')
dataset.shape  #(5728, 2)

#Checking for duplicates and removing them
dataset.drop_duplicates(inplace = True)
dataset.shape  #(5695, 2)
#Checking for any null entries in the dataset
print (pd.DataFrame(dataset.isnull().sum()))
'''
text  0
spam  0
'''
#Using Natural Language Processing to cleaning the text to make one corpus
# Cleaning the texts
import re
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.stem.porter import PorterStemmer
#Every mail starts with 'Subject :' will remove this from each text 
dataset['text']=dataset['text'].map(lambda text: text[1:])
dataset['text'] = dataset['text'].map(lambda text:re.sub('[^a-zA-Z0-9]+', ' ',text)).apply(lambda x: (x.lower()).split())
ps = PorterStemmer()
corpus=dataset['text'].apply(lambda text_list:' '.join(list(map(lambda word:ps.stem(word),(list(filter(lambda text:text not in set(stopwords.words('english')),text_list)))))))

# Creating the Bag of Words model
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
cv = CountVectorizer()
X = cv.fit_transform(corpus.values).toarray()
y = dataset.iloc[:, 1].values

# Splitting the dataset into the Training set and Test set
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.20)

# Fitting Naive Bayes classifier to the Training set
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
classifier = MultinomialNB(alpha=1.0, class_prior=None, fit_prior=True)
classifier.fit(X_train , y_train)

# Predicting the Test set results
y_pred = classifier.predict(X_test)
```

I practiced on no. just today I shifted on the text so I have this model ready with 0.98 accuracies but when I am trying to predict on a new text input I am getting errors.

```
subject = "hello this is a test"
classifier.predict([[subject]])
```

the error which I got is

> FutureWarning: Beginning in version 0.22, arrays of bytes/strings will be converted to decimal numbers if dtype='numeric'. It is recommended that you convert the array to a float dtype before using it in scikit-learn, for example by using your_array = your_array.astype(np.float64).
> return f(**kwargs)

`ValueError: matmul: Input operand 1 has a mismatch in its core dimension 0, with gufunc signature (n?,k),(k,m?)->(n?,m?) (size 29223 is different from 1)`

Any suggestions or possible solutions which I can try

I also tried converting the sentence

````
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfTransformer
vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
tfidfconverter = TfidfTransformer()
text = "Hello world!"
text = vectorizer.transform([text]).toarray()
text = tfidfconverter.transform(text).toarray()
label = classifier.predict(text)[0]```

but got a NotFittedError: Vocabulary not fitted or provided.
````